# Unknown column 'uuid' in 'field list' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

i am trying to create a column **"unique"** filled with UUID in my **"users"** table i don't want it to be primary and as i try to register user i am facing this error **"Unknown column 'uuid' in 'field list'"**
i have made a new laravel project and just used **"Auth"** command on it
**If You Have Any Other Way To Execute This Please Do Share i just want a unique 5 to 8 character code for my user**

**Here's My Users Migration:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('unique');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Here's My User Model:-**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use App\Models\Concerns\UsesUuid;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     protected $guarded = []; // YOLO



  public $incrementing = false;


   protected $keyType = 'string';

   protected static function boot()
   {
     parent::boot();
  self::creating(function ($user) {
      $user->uuid = (string) Uuid::generate(4);
  });
   }


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'uuid',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


}
```

**Here's a Picture Of My DB:-**
[image]

this is my first time using UUID so i did as per the tutorials 
as i am a beginner at laravel as well as programming i don't know whats casing the problem 
Please Help

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your migration script creates a column `unique` not `uuid`, that's the reason you are getting `column uuid not not found`. (please look at to your phpmyadmin screenshot second column)

change this `$table->uuid('unique');` to `$table->uuid('uuid')->unique();` that may create you a column for uuid.

Comment: Ohh Thanks It Worked